# Grouping results by category, then splitting the result in to days?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently using the following

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) as count
FROM
table
GROUP BY category
```

Which is counting how many items are posted in each category, however what I'd like to do is get an array of results for each category that reads like this

```
Category: FirstCategory:
    Date: 26/03/2019,
    Posts: 156,
    Date: 27/03/2019,
    Posts: 127
Category: SecondCategory:
    Date: 26/03/2019,
    Posts: 122,
    Date: 27/03/2019,
    Posts: 135
```

Is this type of thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by category and date in SQL. Then group the result by category in PHP:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT category, date, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY category, date
");

$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['category']][$row['date']] = $row['count'];
}
```

You will get an array like this:

```
[
    'FirstCategory' => [
        '26/03/2019' => 156,
        '27/03/2019' => 127,
    ],
    'SecondCategory' => [
        '26/03/2019' => 122,
        '27/03/2019' => 135,
    ],
]
```